# How do i display error messages when i have many input fields by using Adobe Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flexbuilder, error-reporting

I am a beginner to Flex development (so keep it in mind when answering) and i have a Adobe Flex form in which it has many input Field. I use VBox, HBox as container to layout the page.

So the question is: How do i display error messages when i have many input fields by using Adobe Flex ? And what should i do to show error message when i have many input Field with absolute position ?

There are good resources about it in web ?

Good answers will gain UPvoting

regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you should use the Validator classes (ie StringValidator) to validate the input on the individual fields. You will end up with a Validator for each input. Flex inputs have built in display of error messages and highlighting to display invalid inputs.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstart/validating_data/

Here's a blog post of mine that outlines the method I use:
http://joelhooks.com/2009/02/01/form-validation-for-the-lazy-programmer-in-flex/

Here's a somewhat more advanced approach utilizing Hamcrest-AS3:
http://www.insideria.com/2009/11/validation-in-flex-with-hamcre.html

Comment: @Joel Hooks Thank you, UPvoting. If you know other resources, share it with us.